# ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, ftp

I was trying to use `ftp` and I am getting the following error:

```
>>> ftp = ftplib.FTP('192.168.248.108')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 118, in __init__
    self.connect(host)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 153, in connect
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I was trying to take it step by step since the whole client and server codes were not running. Help please. Thank you.

**EDIT:**
This is the client side code:

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('192.168.248.128')
ftp.login(user='username', passwd = 'password')
ftp.cwd('/Desktop/FTP')
def placeFile():

    filename = 'myfile.txt'
    ftp.storbinary('STOR '+filename, open(filename, 'rb'))
    ftp.quit()

placeFile()
```

Comment: Yes, what is the problem here?

Comment: You really need to show a [mcve] so readers can have any idea what *could* be the problem you are facing.

Comment: can you connect to this address using another mean?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I tried using `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: if you don't have a FTP server running on localhost, it will be the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check this ip to see if `ftp` service is available, and if it is check the `port` that it is listening on, cause it maybe (rare but possible) is configured to listen on a different port than the standard one - **21** . Also maybe the connection is blocked by a **firewall**, and that is why connection gets refused.

Also haven't seen the whole code of yours but I think another/different problem is this: `def placeFile()`  should be changed to this instead `def placeFile(ftp)` - cause the function `placeFile` doesn't really know that `ftp` references to the ftp client you created above.