# ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused in python 3.6

Tags: python, ftplib

While i am connecting to FTP using python's ftplib module, i am getting below error.

Code:

```
import ftplib
ftp=ftplib.FTP('127.0.0.1')
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/virenv/lib/python3.6/ftplib.py", line 117,
>   in **init**
>       self.connect(host)   File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/virenv/lib/python3.6/ftplib.py", line 152,
>   in connect
>       source_address=self.source_address)   File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/virenv/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724,
>   in create_connection
>       raise err   File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/virenv/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713,
>   in create_connection
>       sock.connect(sa) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Comment: You can't connect. Is there an FTP server running on `localhost:21`? Is there a firewall blocking the connection?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840357/connectionrefusederror-errno-111-connection-refused?rq=1 Have a look at above link. The first answer describes it all.

Comment: i have installed ftp server and working as expected. Thanks ! @KlausD.

Comment: What is the output of `ss -l46n` on the bash prompt?